# Build an APK using terminal

Tags: android, gradle, terminal

I'am trying to generate APK from terminal so first i started with `./gradlew build` but i've got this error and can't find any solution.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not evaluate onlyIf predicate for task ':library:signArchives'.
> path may not be null or empty string. path=''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it 
incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.

BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

any help please.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I updated the code, my bad!

Comment: Are you able to build when not using the Terminal?